# How to filter GraphQL results by a descendent without edges?

Tags: graphql

I just started looking at GraphQL and I am wondering if there is a way to filter results that don't have any nodes. Here is a relatively simple example query:

```
query { 
  organization(login:"GitHub") { 
    repositories(first: 20) {
      edges {
        node {
          name
          pullRequests(first: 5, states: OPEN){
            edges {
              node {
                title
                author{
                  login
                }
                updatedAt
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and here is a subset of the results that query returns:

```
{
  "data": {
    "organization": {
      "repositories": {
        "edges": [
          {
            "node": {
              "name": "gitignore",
              "pullRequests": {
                "edges": [
                  {
                    "node": {
                      "title": "Create new CodeComposerStudio.gitignore",
                      "author": {
                        "login": "wolf99"
                      },
                      "updatedAt": "2017-07-26T20:31:53Z"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "node": {
                      "title": "Create PVS.gitignore",
                      "author": {
                        "login": "cesaramh"
                      },
                      "updatedAt": "2017-05-01T19:42:07Z"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "node": {
                      "title": "gitignore for Magic Software Enterprises product xpa ",
                      "author": {
                        "login": "tommes"
                      },
                      "updatedAt": "2017-05-01T19:41:53Z"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "node": {
                      "title": "Create PSoC.gitignore",
                      "author": {
                        "login": "dbrwn"
                      },
                      "updatedAt": "2017-05-01T19:41:39Z"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "node": {
                      "title": "add ThinkPHP gitignore file",
                      "author": {
                        "login": "swumao"
                      },
                      "updatedAt": "2017-05-01T19:40:53Z"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "node": {
              "name": "dmca",
              "pullRequests": {
                "edges": []
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So I'd like to know if there is a way to modify my query so that it would not return the node named `dmca` since there are no edges on `pullRequests`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using githubs graphql api than it seems that there is no way to filter those edges,
But if you're implementing the graphql server then it's possible to know what the edges nodes are and thus filter it in the edge resolver

Answer (score 0):

According to GitHub `repositories` documentation does not allow that kind of filtering.

```
first: Int
Returns the first n elements from the list.

after: String
Returns the elements in the list that come after the specified cursor.

last: Int
Returns the last n elements from the list.

before: String
Returns the elements in the list that come before the specified cursor.

privacy: RepositoryPrivacy
If non-null, filters repositories according to privacy

orderBy: RepositoryOrder
Ordering options for repositories returned from the connection

affiliations: [RepositoryAffiliation]
Affiliation options for repositories returned from the connection

isLocked: Boolean
If non-null, filters repositories according to whether they have been locked

isFork: Boolean
If non-null, filters repositories according to whether they are forks of another repository
```

So I don't think that can be done.

Comment: Yeah, you could be right. It clearly isn't something that can be done directly; but I was wondering if there was a mechanism in GraphQL itself independent of published schema. I see there are `@include(if: Boolean)` and `@skip(if: Boolean)` directives in GraphQL, but I'm uncertain if that is something that could be used to accomplish my goal.

Comment: include and skip are only to filter part of the query based on client parameters, not based on the returned data /: so it won't help you in this case